# Is Windows 10 File Explorer not implementing alphabetical ordering?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, sorting

I have following three sub-folders in a folder in Windows-10. I sort them by clicking on the Name column-header and they show in the following order:

```
01
1
02
```

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order :

"... To determine which of two strings comes first in alphabetical order, their first letters are compared. If they differ, then the string whose first letter comes earlier in the alphabet comes before the other string "

Now if I compare the first letters of '1' and '02' then clearly '0' comes earlier in the alphabet, which is why it seems logical that above '01' comes before '1'. Very Good!

Then why does '02' NOT come before '1'?

Is Windows-10 FileExplorer sort-by-name NOT sorting by alphabetic ordering? Why not?

Comment: [Natural sort order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order).

Comment: [Sorting for Humans : Natural Sort Order](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/).

Comment: Thanks for the links to "Natural Sort Order" they explain that  the answer to my question is "yes" and why (assuming that Windows 10 uses "natural sort-order").  Your answer should be the accepted answer but of course you can not 'answer" my question because it is said to be a duplicate. Your answer is much better and clearer than anything in the duplicates-section :-)